# Three.dart – Mesh disappears at certain camera positions

Tags: three.js, dart

I have created a "snake" consisting of a sphere as the "head" and a "body" that dynamically extends behind it, and made a camera following the head.

Here is a running example (the body appears after 4 seconds):
https://googledrive.com/host/0B-hk5KngFQXFYkExQkF3VHUtWkE/index.html
(use left and right keys to control the snake)

Sometimes the body mesh (not the head) just disappears for no apparent reason. This does only seem to happen when the camera is below a certain height (use mouse scroll to zoom in/out)

What can be causing this?

Comment: hmm, it looks like three.js thinks your mesh is not visible anymore? Maybe you have to recalculate the boundingbox/boundingsphere of your snake body for every update or let's say for every 10 updates? I am just guessing :)

Comment: this is indeed necessary, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap my comment, the solution is to recalculate the boundingbox or boundingsphere of the snake's body mesh. I would also suggest doing this recalculation not every frame, maybe using a timer or frameCounter.